# Resume MediaPlayer after pressing Home Button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, onpause

I have a MediaPlayer that streams music in the background, when I press the home button the music stops, which what I want, but when I resume back to the application, the music is not there anymore. And when the current track ends, it doesn't loop.

My code is the following:

```
MediaPlayer backgroundMusic;
int length = 0;


//play background music
    backgroundMusic = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.background_music);
    backgroundMusic.start();
    backgroundMusic.setLooping(true);



@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();




    if(backgroundMusic.isPlaying()){
        backgroundMusic.pause();
        length = backgroundMusic.getCurrentPosition();
    }else{
        return;
    }
}


public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer backgroundMusic){
    backgroundMusic.start();
    backgroundMusic.seekTo(length);
}
```

How can I resume the music from where it stopped, when I press the Home Button, and Also make the music loop.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to implement your code with service class if you want your player to play even in background or if you want to store the position save your data in static variable in onpause and restore it onResume of your Activity.

Answer (score 0):

Preserve position of playing in shared preferences and not in local variable

Comment: check the link about how to use shared preferences to store data persistently http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values